# Gradle Wrapper 1.11 vs 2.3?

Tags: spring, gradle, gradlew

I'm following [Building a RESTful Web Service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) -- and was wondering why the gradle wrapper version was 1.11 instead of 2.3? I tried 2.3 and it worked.

Is there a downside to using 2.3 instead of the suggested 1.11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably the reason is, that at the time of the creation of the tutorial the stable Gradle version was 1.11, and the tutorial just wasn't updated since then. Usually there is no downside to use a newer version, except if there are some features used, which are now deprecated or removed in a newer version.

Comment: Ok, that's what I was assuming. The oddity was that spring-boot was at its latest version. So I though there was an off chance that spring boot was only compatible with gradle 1.1.